# Cannot add any images

Tags: xcode

Every time i add an image for i get the error below.
For some reason even if i rename it it still doesn't work, this problem was happening before on another project so i deleted it and started again. i have already checked for duplicate images that did get rid of the error however once i built the project the the picture was blank and i get a message saying

2013-11-07 16:45:28.613 Chiswick W4[1812:60b] Could not load the "1frivoli.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "Studentathome.Chiswick-W4"

need some help urgently!!

Also i would like to add i can take a screen shot of that image and input it however i will have to do this is a worst case scenario i just want to know why my images don't work.

thank you
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently if you change an image on windows to .png it doesn't actually convert the file to .png, the reason i was doubtful that this could be the issue is because when developing for android there was no issue with this type of file type. All i needed to do was use an online converter to change all the images to .png.

Answer (score 0):

Under the the tab 'Build Phases' in your target settings, make sure that the images are listen under 'Copy Bundle Resources', and if not then be sure to add them.

Comment: when i do that with that image i get this error and with a couple other images i still get it however when i do it with other random images it doesn't come up and it works fine